# Why XPath can't find tags?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, domdocument

I have xml file and PHP script o process this XML. Why script can't find tags? Why xpath is failing with warnings:

```
PHP Warning:  DOMXPath::query(): Invalid predicate in test.php on line 7
PHP Warning:  DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression in test.php on line 7
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in test.php on line 9
```

doc.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rootTag>
    <div id="tag-id"></div>
    <div id="tag-id"></div>
    <div id="tag-id"></div>
    <div id="tag-id"></div>
    <div id="tag-id"></div>
</rootTag>
```

test.php

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('./doc.xml');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$tags = $xpath->query('//div[@id="tag-id"');

foreach ($tags as $node) {
    print($node->nodeName);
}

?>
```

Comment: You are missing a `]` in your xpath : `//div[@id="tag-id"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you query is almost correct. You have just forgotten putting last closing "`]`" char.

It ought to be:

```
$tags = $xpath->query('//div[@id="tag-id"]');
```

instead:

```
$tags = $xpath->query('//div[@id="tag-id"');
```